# How can I derive an address and port from -[NSNetService addresses] so I can use it with NSURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, networking, nsdata, cocoahttpserver

I'd like to use [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) to set up peer-to-peer communication between different instances of an application on a network. Setting up the server was quite easy, but writing the client is another story.

I have the server broadcasting over Bonjour. My client is able to find and resolve the service, but I'm stuck when it comes to getting the actual IP address and port that I can use with `NSURL`.

If I call `[NSNetService addresses]` I get the addresses in the form of an array of `NSData` objects, which is fine for low level networking purposes. But my plan was to use `stringWithContentsOfURL:` on the client side to make requests, so I need the addresses as a string or something.

Is this a sensible approach? If so, how can I get the addresses of the resolved `NSNetService` in a format that works with `NSURL`?

Comment: This is an old thread but I've got the same issue - any chance you could elaborate on how you solved this with the confirmed "answer" below? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct one from `-hostName` and `-port` perhaps?